# Forcing Sandbox mode for GameCenter

Tags: ios, testing, game-center

I'm trying to force access to GameCenter in sandbox mode on several devices (iPod5 6.1.3, iPod5 7.0, iPad 6.1.3, iPh4 7.0).

Typically, GameCenter will prompt the user on launch to log into GC, but the problem is all the devices specified have used a workaround in the past to force the launch popup to not appear (if you accept to sign in, hit cancel, relaunch, 3 times, then GameCenter will stop prompting the user). I've read that I can factory reset the devices, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Is there any way to force GameCenter to load in Sandbox outside of the app? Or is there some way to force GameCenter to start prompting the user again?

I've tried signing out of GameCenter, uninstalling the app, and reinstalling the app, but that only works for sim and not actual devices. I also tried using a Sandbox account to make a purchase in app, hoping that would force GC to log in to the respective account, but that worked to no avail.

P.S. I'm in QA, so my programming knowledge is limited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings

Keep in mind this will also reset all other settings including remembered wifi networks.